# Custom PopOver with pattern border

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, custom-controls, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to implement popover like that:
[image: Custom PopOver]

I've spent quite a lot of time trying to customize `UIPopoverController` and `UIPopoverBackgroundView`. As I understand my task is impossible with public API for popovers.
It is possible:

1. To use small image with fixed corners and stretchable center, in that case I'll have stretched stripes on the side. And also I'll have image "under" the arrow.
2. Fill border with stripes, but in that case I don't have rounded corners. I also have annoying inner shadow inside:
   [image]

   backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"airmail_pattern"]];

Is there any other way to reuse standard popover or I have to implement that behavior using just UIViewController?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

WEPopover seems to do what you want to do. It has custom background property, which I guess could be used for this purpose. (I haven't used this yet)

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: Thanks. Custom background implemented in WEPopover is same, as you can do yourself using `UIPopoverBackgroundView`. You can set fixed corners of the background, but other parts will be stretched. In my case it won't work.