# Creating a UIKit popover on iPad with custom background images

Tags: ios, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad application that will display a popover using custom artwork. From an earlier question ([Custom popover with pattern border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762832/custom-popover-with-pattern-border), I learned about the UIPopoverBackgroundView class. But it's not clear to me how I am supposed to provide my images.

My designer provided me with a single image, which is easy enough to slice into components. If I simply implement drawRect in a UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass, I can use non-stretched left and right images and a stretched center image. But then it's not clear how I provide my custom arrow image (which points up) as presentation of the arrow is derived from the base class properties.

I looked at UIPopoverBackgroundView.h but I don't see any methods or properties that refer to images, just properties of the view.

Am I going about this the right way? Does UIPopoverBackgroundView actually let me provide complete background images for a custom popover appearance? How do I provide my custom images to a UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass? Do I need to instead subclass UIView to achieve a completely custom popover appearance?

I am currently targeting iOS 5.

Edit: I also found another question, [using UIPopoverBackgroundView class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205846/using-uipopoverbackgroundview-class). My question looks like a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing my own popover view class.

Comment: Do you want to use it? I could put together an example project on github.